# Need to start my application on Windows logon screen

Tags: .net-framework, c#, windows-services

I have a problem. I have a GSM device and I wrote an application in C#. The app continuously receives SMSs and stores them in a database, but when Windows gets restarted, I have to explicitly login back to start the service again.

How can I be sure that my application starts automatically if Windows restarts?

Comment: You can configure Windows to automatically start any application you want when the user logs into their account.  You can even configure Windows to automatically log into the account if you want.

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Answer (score 7):

Write the program as a Windows [service](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2005/03/15/396428.aspx), instead of an application.

Comment: This won't launch it on full reboot on the logon screen.

Comment: services launch regardless of login

Comment: OK, yes. You would have to write an interface application and a service if the current application is WinForms / WCF etc.. If he wants just the winform, then GINA or something would be required. Coffee still kicking in for the day.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows XP you can modify or use GINA, but this is not a simple thing to test!

http://www.codealias.info/technotes/custom_pre-logon_processing_in_ms_windows_using_gina_hooks

For Windows 7 the process has changed, but still, there is a better method for most situations:

Use [Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545027.aspx) and either Autologon or TweakUI to autologon.

Then add the application to the startup applications.

---

Edit

The above for is for trying to run a pure application, as Keltari pointed out the alternative is to make the application a service.